# Liveagent: Possible to use Custom Chat Window without creating a Force.com Site?

Tags: liveagent

From the Chat Button edit screen (Setup->Customize->Live Agent->Chat Buttons & Invitations):

[image]

Note that "Custom Chat Page" does not have an input box.  If I set up a Force.com Site, I get the input box and can assign a VF page from the site.  I am specifically trying to avoid the need to set up a Force.com site.  Now, note the end of the introductory text:

> If you do not have a Force.com site to use for these customizations, you can manually modify the chat button code on the next page.

While that is true for the images, it doesn't seem to be the case for the custom pages; in my case the Custom Chat Page.  When I do configure a Force.com Site and select a Custom Chat Page, the generated HTML/JS on the "next page" (view page) include no reference to the custom chat page, by name, url, or SF ID.  Is this just a mistake in the UI message, left over from when only the images could be overridden?

I understand that a custom chat page would normally be hosted via a publicly accessible Force.com site page, but in my case, I'm implementing Live Agent chat for users of the org to chat with other users of the org - no non-authenticated user will ever use chat.  The OOB chat window works, but I need to customize the chat window.  Am I stuck creating a site?

Comment: It seems to me as an oversight or a bug on Live Agent. Theoretically, you could implement live agent in your customer portal (without a site) so not allowing you to customize the chat window without a site doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for your situation, you still have to use a Force.com Site because LiveAgent was originally created with public end users in mind. As you noted, you only get to select a Custom Chat Page after you have selected a Force.com Site.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick look at the [Live Agent Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/index.htm), it appears what you'd need to do is customize the visual force pages and use static resources to hold any images that you might want to use. Your org's Live Agent pages are going to be in your salesforce instance and presumably available for editing/customization.

Comment: The issue is that I can't assign a visual force page to be used.  In the image in my question, note that "Custom Chat Page" does not have an input box.  If I set up a Force.com Site, I get the input box and can assign a VF page from the site.  I am specifically trying to avoid the need to set up a Force.com site.  I've edited my question to make this clearer.

Comment: From what I saw through browsing the Developer's guide, it appeared to me as though there were VisualForce pages that could be modified/customized, including a custom chat page, but perhaps it hasn't been updated recently. I saw where the console isn't available to new installs, so that could be part of the issue. Anything you added for images or chat would still be static resources. Perhaps this is one to file a case with support on.

Comment: In other words, your answer is not based on experience. Actually, in order to expose a Visualforce page publicly for LiveAgent, one must create a site.