# adding live agent user photo on chat window

Tags: customization, liveagent

I want to have the photo of the live agent who has accepted to chat .His photo should appear on the chat window of visitor.

I tried using "Chat Window Branding Image", i think its good for displaying company logo no the live agents photograph

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways of implementing Live Agent. Without knowing what level of customization in your installation you already have, it could be difficult for someone to give you an answer. You might want to look at the following post to see if it answers your question: [Liveagent: Possible to use Custom Chat Window without creating a Force.com Site?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31934/liveagent-possible-to-use-custom-chat-window-without-creating-a-force-com-site).

If it doesn't, the best i can do is refer you to the [Live Agent Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_customizing_deployments.htm?language=en), the [Live Agent REST API Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_understanding_resources.htm?language=en) and the [Service Cloud Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_service_cloud.meta/workbook_service_cloud/service0_intro.htm?language=en).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that doesnt help me, What i need is photo to be shown in the chat window of the live agent.. I tried using "Chat Window Branding Image" but it displays at top of the window which i think is good for displaying company logo ...

Comment: Try searching using this search engine: http://findsf.info/ to see if anything comes up that might help you. Its salesforce specific. I only searched here on SF.SE.

Comment: now i have created the custom chat page with the help of code from live agent guide.It works fine same as standard chat window.I have to get the live agent name

Comment: now i have created custom chat page using code from eveloper guide.I have to get the live agent name on the chat page .so far i have done this,               public with sharing class liveagentclass {
String AgentId;
public liveagentclass (){
AgentId=Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
}
public List<Live Agent Session> las {get;set;}

}                                                         but it is giving me this following error"Error: Compile Error: expecting a right angle bracket, found 'Agent' at line 6 column 19".I am trying to get agent user name using soql query.

Comment: You can debug your JavaScript yourself as described in [How do I start to debug my own Visualforce/JavaScript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36715/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-visualforce-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

A tad bit late, but I have posted the solution here:

https://systemdebug.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/live-agent-rest-api-connectapi/

Basically, you need to use the getDetails method to get the user id, having that information you can retrieve the photo.